# Get location of specific string in array SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a code that counts spaces before a string - see sample table called TEST

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AB FEB EB |

in this case i want to count the spaces in front of "EB" which should be 2 but my query returns 1 since it considers "FEB" as "EB". How do i specifically make the query only count spaces preceding "EB"

Thanks!

```
select id
, REGEXP_COUNT(  
            SPLIT( 
               TRIM(
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '[^[:digit:]]', ' ')
               ), 'EB'
             )[0] , ' '
         ) count_of_spaces
from  TEST
```

Comment: So just like `FEB` is not `EB` I assume `EBX` is not `EB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split by space, and then ask for the [ARRAY_POISTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_position.html) of 'EB' you will find the exact first match location:

```
    
select column1    
    ,SPLIT(column1, ' ') as s
    ,ARRAY_POSITION('EB'::variant, s) as p 
from values
 ('EB'), 
 ('FEB EB'), 
 ('AB FEB EB'), 
 ('AB FEB EBX EB'), 
 ('AB FEB EB EBX'), 
 ('AB FEB FEB EB AB FEB FEB EB')
;
```

| COLUMN1 | S | P |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EB | [ "EB" ] | 0 |
| FEB EB | [ "FEB", "EB" ] | 1 |
| AB FEB EB | [ "AB", "FEB", "EB" ] | 2 |
| AB FEB EBX EB | [ "AB", "FEB", "EBX", "EB" ] | 3 |
| AB FEB EB EBX | [ "AB", "FEB", "EB", "EBX" ] | 2 |
| AB FEB FEB EB AB FEB FEB EB | [ "AB", "FEB", "FEB", "EB", "AB", "FEB", "FEB", "EB" ] | 3 |